# Simple STR_TO_DATE issue in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I am getting in a date like "Dec 2012" and want to turn it into a date like "2012-12-01". I am using STR_TO_DATE('Dec 2012','%b %Y') and it ends up looking like 2012-12-00. Any ideas how I can get it to set it to the first day of the month?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Dec 2012','%b %Y'), '%Y-%m-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', 'Dec 2012') ,'%d %b %Y');
```

**OR**

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('Dec 2012','%b %Y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```